# How to know Laravel version and where is it defined?

Tags: laravel

How to know Laravel version and where is it defined?

Is Laravel version is defined inside my application directory or somewhere in global server side directory?

**UPDATE**

Sorry, the main question is where the version is defined? Where does

```
php artisan --version
```

takes it's answer?

**UPDATE 2**

The goal is to investigate, who (of us) has changed Laravel version on our site. Could it be changed by github repository edition only? Or server write access was also required?

Comment: Do you want to use version in your code ?

Answer (score 206):

run `php artisan --version` from your console.

The version string is defined here:

https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php

```
/**
 * The Laravel framework version.
 *
 * @var string
 */
 const VERSION = '5.5-dev';
```

Comment: composer.json also look :)

Comment: @NikolaSpalevic  That was my first thought, but with semantic version numbers you won't see the patch number. If you run the artisan command you will.

Comment: @btl please, also answer the second part, where is it defined?

Comment: Good point mentioning Application.php as Laravel doesn't seem to know its version sometimes. My composer.json says "5.6.*", the constant knows it's "5.6.18", but using "artisan --version" gives me: "Laravel Framework 7.8.1" - which doesn't even exist.

Answer (score 50):

```
  1)  php artisan -V

  2)  php artisan --version
```

AND its define at the **composer.json** file

```
"require": {
        ...........
        "laravel/framework": "^6.2",
        ...........
    },
```

Comment: The composer.json should be the real answer, you can tell which version it is without even having to have PHP installed in your system.

Answer (score 36):

If you want to know the specific version then you need to check composer.lock file and search For

> "name": "laravel/framework",

you will find your version in next line

> "version": "v5.7.9",

Comment: Except you'd want 5.4.* so you can install security patches. Which still won't tell you the version number then :)

Answer (score 31):

If you want to know the user version in your code, then you can use using `app()` helper function

```
app()->version();
```

It is defined in this file `../src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php`

Hope it will help :)

Answer (score 18):

**CASE - 1**

**Run this command in your project..**

```
php artisan --version
```

**You will get version of laravel installed in your system like this..**

[image]

**CASE - 2**

**Also you can check `laravel` version in the `composer.json` file in `root` directory.**

[image]

Answer (score 10):

### Step 1:

go to: `/vendor/laravel/framework/src.Illuminate/Foundation`:

[image: go to: <code>/vendor/laravel/framework/src.Illuminate/Foundation</code>]

### Step 2:

Open application.php file

[image: Open application.php file]

### Step 3:

Search for "version". The below indicates the version.

[image: Open application.php file]

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: This answer should be reformatted to have the links render as images. You will be less likely to be flagged for low quality if you do.

Answer (score 7):

Run this command in your project folder location in cmd

```
php artisan --version
```

Answer (score 5):

Yet another way is to read the composer.json file, but it can end with wildcard character `*`

Comment: Incorrect. The `composer.json` doesn't show the installed version. It show the minimum version required and upgrade policy. If you upgraded your app, chances are it won't match your `composer.json`. Instead you should look at the `composer.lock`, this file shows the currently installed version of all dependencies.

Answer (score 5):

Multiple way we can find out laravel version such as,

Using Command

```
php artisan --version
  or
php artisan -v
```

From Composer.json

From Vendor Directory

```
/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php
```

Answer (score 3):

In your Laravel deployment it would be

/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php

to see who changed your Laravel version look at what's defined in composer.json.  If you have "laravel/framework": "5.4.*", then it will update to the latest after composer update is run.  Composer.lock is the file that results from running a composer update, so really see who last one to modify the composer.json file was (hopefully you have that in version control). You can read more about it here https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md

Answer (score 2):

You can also check with composer:

```
composer show laravel/framework
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're like me and want to show the Laravel version and app version on the footer you can create a Blade directive in `AppServiceProvider`. Blade directives are placed in the boot method of the `AppServiceProvider` and example code may like something like

```
Blade::directive('laravelVersion', function () {
    return "<?php echo app()->version(); ?>";
});
```

then in the blade template, you call it like `@laravelVersion` and it will show the current laravel version.

If you want, you can read more about blade directive [here](https://laravelblade.com/using-at-route-instead-of-route-in-laravel-blade)

Answer (score 2):

You can find this on Composer.json file -> root directory

Answer (score 1):

You can view the result of `dd(\Illuminate\Foundation\Application::VERSION)`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Laravel 9 or higher. You can get a quick overview of your application's configuration, drivers, and environment via the `about` Artisan command:

`php artisan about`

Official doc [Application Overview](https://laravel.com/docs/master/configuration#application-overview)

Answer (score 0):

Any of the following will suffix :
`php artisan --version`

`php artisan about`

Also, locally, you can intentionally generate an error and you will have a handful information about your app.  Something like this: [image: laravel error page]