# Trait 'Illuminate\Notifications\HasDatabaseNotifications' not found

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, migrate

I deployed my Laravel site to cPanel shared hosting and migrated my DB to the hosting's DB. When I try to enter the site by login password, the error is:

```
Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException (E_UNKNOWN)
Trait 'Illuminate\Notifications\HasDatabaseNotifications' not found

/path/to/site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Notifications/Notifiable.php

<?php

namespace Illuminate\Notifications;

trait Notifiable
{
    use HasDatabaseNotifications, RoutesNotifications;
}
```

Arguments

```
"Trait 'Illuminate\Notifications\HasDatabaseNotifications' not found"
```

Comment: What version of laravel you are using?

Comment: It would be worth checking if `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Notifications/HasDatabaseNotifications.php` actually exists on the server and wasn't missed in the migration.

Comment: @MihirBhende laravel 5.6

Comment: okay great because in 5.2, this class is not present. Can you check as @1000Nettles suggested if the class is present? If yes, can you try running `run composer dump-autoload` ?

Comment: @1000Nettles I didn't do any migrate by artisan. I exported my mysql db from localhost to shared hosting. May be problem in this? But in a shared hosting no terminal given.

Comment: @MihirBhende I don't have terminal in hosting. That's a shared((

Comment: I have a feeling that your hosting's Laravel version differs from the version you were developing with locally. Double-check the versions between the two. https://stackoverflow.com/a/44637834/823549

Comment: @1000Nettles says that's versions equal. Laravel v. 5.6.20

Comment: Very odd! In your `composer.lock` file on both versions, what is the version value for `"name": "laravel/framework"`?

Comment: @1000Nettles "laravel/framework": "5.6.*"

Comment: Even weirder. You may have to reach out to the support team of your host and ask them to run a `composer update` on your site as you have no CLI access. Sorry I couldn't be of more help, but running that command should update all of the `vendor` directory to the latest versions defined in `composer.json`.

Comment: @1000Nettles thank you very much. I solved my problem, by commenting HasDatabaseNotifications

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem solved by commenting HasDatabaseNotifications:

```
<?php

namespace Illuminate\Notifications;

trait Notifiable
{
    use /*HasDatabaseNotifications, */RoutesNotifications;
}
```