# How to find out the Laravel "app" (laravel/laravel) version and where is it defined?

Tags: php, laravel

Before getting to the question, let me just say that this is NOT a duplicate of:
[How to know Laravel version and where is it defined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44637811/how-to-know-laravel-version-and-where-is-it-defined)

What I am interested in, is how to figure out which version (GitHub's tag) was used when the Laravel "app" was created? So not the [`laravel/framework`](https://github.com/laravel/framework) version, as this was already explained in the other answer, but the Laravel "starter app" [`laravel/laravel`](https://github.com/laravel/laravel) version?

(I am interested in this so I could compare the differences on GitHub, but I don't know which tag/branch was used when the original app was created over a year ago.)

Comment: isnt the [tag in github](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/tags) named after the version?

Comment: yes, but once you download the release and install locally, you don't know (after a year+) which release of the laravel/laravel was downloaded...all I could find was the laravel/framework version, which is not the same

Comment: the convention on versioning is that, you should not modify the code without incrementing the version number. hence, you can check your laravel version and use that as a reference for checking the tags in github. yes, i know `laravel/laravel` and `laravel/framework` are two different things, however `laravel/laravel` is just another composer project that refers to `laravel/framework`. your first link for `php artisan --version` will show your local copy laravel version. alternatively, if you are so doubtful, just install a random latest package that require laravel - you will hit something.

Comment: thanks for your help, but the problem with "php artisan --version" is that the framework version was already updated (because of php 8)...I could still check the version prior to the upgrade or even check the very first commit on my repo and check the tag history on laravel/laravel github, but it just seems like too much detective work just for finding the correct tag (especially since I have several laravel projects to upgrade)

Comment: **was used when the Laravel "app" was created?** -- not possible, unless you are wiling to check on your scm. digging old stuff is part of the job description. if you are using git, you could simply checkout to the earlier commits (before upgrade, or better, when the git repository initialized) and do the `php artisan --version` there. composer doesnt keep tabs on what version for stuffs you previously install given its the job for version control.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could check when you did commit your project the first time to your own git and see what version of `laravel/laravel` was current at the time.

Answer (score 0):

You can check your composer.json file:

```
"require": {
    "laravel/framework": "^8.75",
}
```

Comment: Since this value gets updated when you update the framework, this answer is false.