# Laravel can't update .env, artisan is broken

Tags: php, laravel

I want to enable logging debug level in Laravel. I added a line to config/app.php

```
'log' => env('APP_LOG', 'single'),
'log_level' => env('APP_LOG_LEVEL', 'debug'),
```

Now I need to re-read the configuration file. I found that this can be done using

```
php artisan config:cache
php artisan config:clear
```

But I get such a string with any request to artisan.

```
��Vaartisan��OO�@���E"�$��B���FEB$.���=��Y��'��o���C{
Vy�;og��v>�)�|�m�vCm�f�>���g/��=�
                                  ��J�Ȟk���:U�?�6���5�
                                                      ب�n�K��pv�V��cRػQQʘ�Vl٫�%F�@f�UΓK�T�����)=1�H!�e���ѿ�t<·Sc��Ϥ��@C[���7^��jƗ S*Җ�td�ՆEm��H-]��F������|�4Q�q�l�����Zy�,t<<�a��Y6$�X|��/��|�\
                                                                                                                                                                                                ѫ6���-����c���X�jX8[�#�m���s��uP��_���<�l��=�&`�ᷞ�w��nngX���K�jؽ��i���U�$�sh1�Ed���ס�Vh�6\�(y�q�¡h`�Ƶ�Ô�    G+
$���>Y��l�X9�jԚG3c�ly~�,
�� #�bM�� �eZv}��   �.���Eezc�(=BT1�؉M�j�ax��m%�K\�-=tM�l7ﯜEmdg�j~�W��m���?�/{�F��{ �P�X�ힳw��N.�r�U��P�g�[�Qz�*����v�bH���44
x�P���w0�   ��o�&W{�#�vd�i�8��:�^ǿ}�}n
```

What am I doing wrong?

**php -v**

```
PHP 7.4.19 (cli) (built: May 20 2021 05:25:29) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with the ionCube PHP Loader + ionCube24 v10.4.3, Copyright (c) 2002-2020, by ionCube Ltd.
    with Zend OPcache v7.4.19, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
```

I don't know Laravel version.

Comment: According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44637834/231316), you should be able to get your version by inspecting a specific file. I just checked and it appears to be the case even for version 11.

Comment: Hmm, my first guess was that maybe there were some ANSI escape sequences that your shell couldn't interpret, but that's usually still textual. That "ionCube PHP Loader" would be related to possibly encrypted/obfuscated code, which could be binary.

Comment: cat composer.json
"��Vacomposer.json�TMo�0
                       =����[�m�
                                k�
��zk:��[�,i������>�v�8��!����GQ��I~����$�`�F��g:����x�UD��|" and etc